# Indoor location based on iBeacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, ibeacon, triangulation

I want to locate an object position inside a house( one floor).

The object will have a iBeacon on it.

What are the best approach.

With api, i can get distance from the iBeacon, but this doesn't reflect position.

One idea was to have 4 fixed iBeacon on the floor, but seem's i can't get the distance from the moving iBeacon to a fixed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

iBeacon isn't the right technology for this - at least not with a single receiver.

iBeacon only gives you an approximate distance. If you have multiple beacons in known locations then you can try and triangulate the receiver's position but you can't use this information to determine the location of another transmitter in an unknown location - only estimate its distance from the receiver.

Even using known, fixed transmitters it is difficult to locate the receiver with any accuracy due to the nature of the Bluetooth signals.

If you had multiple iBeacon receivers on the floor at known locations then it might be possible to determine the location of the transmitter.

Comment: This is correct.  Systems like The Tile App https://www.thetileapp.com/ let you locate Bluetooth transmitters, but they are non-directional.  To get direction, you need multiple transmitters and a more sophisticated device like a smartphone in the fixed position.